# How to remove target from PlayCommand?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avplayer

I am building an audioPlayer on *Xamarin.iOS* using [XamarinMediaManager](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager) which is based on `AVPlayer` on iOS.

To play/pause a track from the lock screen i added the following handlers to `PlayCommand` and `PauseCommand` like this:

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter.Shared.PlayCommand.AddTarget(LockScreenPlay);
MPRemoteCommandCenter.Shared.PauseCommand.AddTarget(LockScreenPause);
 //..

 private MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus LockScreenPlay(MPRemoteCommandEvent arg)
{
  //..
    PlaybackController.Play();
  // ..
}
 private MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus LockScreenPause(MPRemoteCommandEvent arg)
{
 //..
    PlaybackController.Pause();
 //..
}
```

**The problem**

When i access the controller several times the `LockScreenPlay/Pause` gets executed several times, How i could remove old handlers when the View is unloaded?

Ps: i've already tried to `RemoveTarget` in the `ViewWillDisappear` method:

```
KMPRemoteCommandCenter.Shared.PlayCommand.RemoveTarget(this);
```

but that didn't work, what i am doing wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPRemoteCommandCenter.Shared.PlayCommand.AddTarget(LockScreenPlay);` will return a `NSObject`. If you want to remove this action you should use this api like:

```
// Add play command
playCommand =  MPRemoteCommandCenter.Shared.PlayCommand.AddTarget(LockScreenPlay);
// Remove play command later
MPRemoteCommandCenter.Shared.PlayCommand.RemoveTarget(playCommand);
```

In this way, you need to record the commands every time you have added. Then remove them when you want.

Also you can try to use OC selector to add play command:

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter.Shared.PlayCommand.AddTarget(this, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("LockScreenPlay:"));
[Export("LockScreenPlay:")]
private void LockScreenPlay(MPRemoteCommand command)
{
   ...
}
```

In this way, you can use `MPRemoteCommandCenter.Shared.PlayCommand.RemoveTarget(this);` to remove all the commands you have added. So do pause commands.

Comment: Thank you, i will try that out later